# Phone number regex extraction from formatted string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, phone-number

Given the phone numbers are all on this format:

```
(999) 999-9999 Ext.9999"
```

I want to return everything to the second space, e.g.:

```
(999) 999-9999
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this valid the valid scenerio '(999) 999-9999 ext.9999' i.e., `ext` is in small letters ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your string is in s:

```
   string s = "(999) 999-9999 Ext.9999";
   string number = s.Split(" Ext")[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a perfect match, you can use this expression:

```
string s = "(999) 999-9999 Ext.9999";
Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"(?<nr>\([0-9]{3}\)\s+[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4})");
if (m.Groups["nr"].Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["nr"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular expression. Use [`Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx). Then concatenate the first two elements back together.

Comment: Maybe. Rather harsh if so. I was the first answer and supplied the same answer as the accepted answer. Sans code sample. Not familiar enough with C#.

Answer (score 1):

Where `s` contains the full sting. If truely "all on this format" *exactly*, then you could just take the first 14 characters:

```
string number = s.SubString(0, 14);
```

Or a bit more flexible, and safer:

```
var idx = s.IndexOf(" Ext");
//good idea to check if idx == -1
string number = s.SubString(0, idx);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one:

```
    string s = "(999) 999-9999 Ext.9999";
    string phonenumber1 = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?i)\s*ext\.\d+", "");
```

Comment: Why remove what you don't want? Isn't it better to specify what you do want?

Comment: @WouterH, do you think a shorter pattern will be inefficient ? also the unnecessary part was less than the required part.

Comment: I have no problems with efficiency... Think about it: if you have a pattern that extracts the required part, you can reuse it on any text of any length surrounded by anything. So it's more future proof and cleaner for future developers that will need to work on that code one day without knowing the exact input. Why is he stripping that 'ext.' again? Oh he wants the phone number, not very clear isn't it? The same applies for the `.Split` methods proposed here.